# Как на debian 12 поставить pacman?

Tags: debian

Я пробовал сделать также как пишут в любом гайде в интернете:
`sudo apt-get -y install pacman`

Установка проходила успешно, но команду `pacman` банально не видит

```
$ pacman -Ss node
-bash: pacman: command not found
```

Comment: Никак. А даже если и установите какими-то обходными путями, то в итоге просто сломаете систему

Comment: Другой путь пробовал? /usr/games/pacman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вас интересует не сами пакеты арча, а именно применение синтаксиса пакетного менеджера схожего с `pacman` то гляньте в сторону [pacapt](https://github.com/icy/pacapt)

> An ArchLinux's pacman-like shell wrapper for many package managers. 56KB and run anywhere.